Approximation Theorem of Whitney embedding
I was reading page 26 of Morris W. Hirsch's Differential Topology and came across the following approximation theorem. Could you tell me where I can find a more detailed and updated discussion of this theorem, especially for the case of $k \le 2n$?
Approximation Theorem:
For any $C^r$ map $g: M \to \mathbb{R}^k$ (where $k \geq 2n + 1$) and any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $C^r$ embedding $f: M \to \mathbb{R}^k$ such that:
$$
   |f(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon, \quad \forall x \in M.
   $$

What do you mean by the case $k\le 2n$? The theorem is stated for $k\ge 2n+1$ and the bound is sharp in general.

As a very simple example, let $g : S^1 \to mathbb R^2$ be the immersed figure 8. Then there is no nearby embedding $S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$, and so the dimension requirement is sharp.

What I'm curious about is what kind of conclusions we can draw for the case $k \le 2n$. Regarding Whitney's immersion theorem for manifolds, Wikipedia mentions that the critical dimension is an integer related to the binary representation of $ n $. For embeddings, however, the expression for the critical dimension remains an open problem. I wonder whether, for the approximation theorem version, the critical dimension follows the same conclusion.
